# Writing StringBuilder to AWS S3 File

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-s3

I have a `StringBuilder` (**~1GB** size)  which converts to an almost **1GB** `String`. Then it is sent to `AWSS3Client` to be put as a file on `s3`. Now to write the String to `s3`, I need to further convert the string to a `ByteArrayInputStream`, which takes another **1GB**.

```
InputStream dataInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
amazonS3Client.putObject(bucket, key, dataInputStream, new ObjectMetadata());
```

Now I end up with a JVM heap of **3GB**. Is there a way to directly send the 1GB `StringBuilder` directly to `S3` with little over `1GB` heap?

The only way I could think of is to convert `StringBuilder` to a `File` instance (using FileWriter) --> *S3 API which takes File as input*. But this approach requires a `2-IOPS` to the `SSD` -- penalty that I want to avoid.

Any better way to handle the problem is welcome.

**[edit 1]**
(as per comments) The `builder` size changed from `5GB` to `1GB`. I wanted to convey that the `builder`is a huge one (and hence used 5GB previously, which was my mistake)

Comment: There might be a way but why do you have such large memory usage in the first place?

Comment: we get CDC from a db. We want to batch the CDC into files --each file carrying as many CDC rows as possible. The bigger the batches, better it is for the downstream (because now they have to read just hand-ful of files, instead of millions of files)

Comment: I'm not sure how you're handling this , but couldn't you stream the data directly to S3 while extracting it from the db instead of making a big `StringBuilder` and then trying to stream that?

Comment: It is impossible to have a `StringBuilder` of 5GB size. The largest would be 4GB for Java 8 and older. With Java 9 and newer, the maximum size is 2GB. But anyway, there’s no built-in solution but you can just implement your own `InputStream` reading the `StringBuilder`. That’s not that hard…

Comment: its  array of string buffers that accounts to 5GB. However, the problem still holds

Comment: An "array of string buffers". Now I'm confused ;) What does that mean - I thought you had ```StringBuilder``` ?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes we could do that. But the opensource versions available are having bugs, so we had to build one ourselves. Hence this issue.

Comment: I'm still in the dark as to why you're holding such large amounts of data in memory though

Comment: A better approach would be to emit the CDC event into Kinesis Delivery Stream. and output the events into S3. You can control how frequently you want to create the files or size of files.  This way it is fault tolerant as well

Answer (score 0):

The string-oriented classes are frustratingly locked down with `final` in many cases, which means that oftentimes buffers that already exist in memory have to be duplicated. This is probably to do with security but is nevertheless wasteful and frustrating. You should be able to do something with the following if you have a `StringBuilder`. Obviously you'll need a much bigger buffer than in the *illustrative* `main`  method.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 *
 * @author CEHJ
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class CharSequenceInputStream extends InputStream {
    private CharSequence charSequence;
    private int position;
    private CharsetEncoder enc;
    private Charset outputEncoding;
    private CharBuffer cb;
    private ByteBuffer bb;

    public CharSequenceInputStream(CharSequence charSequence) {
        this(charSequence, Charset.forName(System.getProperty("native.encoding", Charset.defaultCharset().name())));
    }

    public CharSequenceInputStream(CharSequence charSequence, Charset outputEncoding) {
        this.charSequence = charSequence;
        this.outputEncoding = outputEncoding;
        position = 0;
        enc = outputEncoding.newEncoder();
        cb = CharBuffer.allocate(1);
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    }

    // For testing only
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.err.printf("Usage: java CharSequenceInputStream <String to be stored> <Output file> [Char encoding for output]");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String content = args[0];
        String outputPath = args[1];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(content);
        CharSequenceInputStream in = null;
        if (args.length > 2) {
            in = new CharSequenceInputStream(sb, Charset.forName(args[2]));
        } else {
            in = new CharSequenceInputStream(sb);
        }

        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath)) {
            int bytesRead = -1;
            final int BUF_SIZE = 8;
            byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE)) > -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int result = -1;
        if (position < charSequence.length()) {
            if (bb.remaining() == bb.capacity() || bb.position() == bb.limit()) {
                // At start - nothing yet has been decoded
                // OR - we've read all bytes in the buffer and need to refill it
                cb.clear();
                bb.clear();
                char currentChar = charSequence.charAt(position++);
                cb.append(currentChar);
                cb.flip();
                enc.reset();
                enc.encode(cb, bb, false);
                enc.encode(cb, bb, true);
                enc.flush(bb);
                bb.flip();
            }
        }
        if (bb.position() < bb.limit()) {
            result = bb.get() & 0xFF;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        return read(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        Objects.checkFromIndexSize(off, len, b.length);
        if (len == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int c = read();
        if (c == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        b[off] = (byte) c;

        int i = 1;
        try {
            for (; i < len; i++) {
                c = read();
                if (c == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                b[off + i] = (byte) c;
            }
        } catch (IOException ee) {
        }
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // NO OP
    }
}
```

Comment: You have basically reinvented [`StringBufferInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html) and the reason why it has been deprecated a quarter century ago (“*This class does not properly convert characters into bytes*”) applies to your code as well.

Comment: Interesting. I shall have to have a think about *why* it doesn't

Comment: @Holger, yes I see the problem. I suppose it could be 'fixed' but I'm not convinced it's really needed. Do you agree that it would be safe to use for 7/8 bit character encodings in an emergency?

Comment: You are effectively writing ASCII or ISO-LATIN-1. The OP’s code used UTF-8 explicitly so this might no match their intention.

Comment: @Holger I wonder if you'd care to have a look at the above? It should now be 'fixed'

Comment: You shouldn’t do `enc.encode(cb, bb, false); enc.encode(cb, bb, true);` Passing `true` means that there are no more chars after the specified buffer, which isn’t true for your single character buffer (unless you’re really at the last char). But in general, this code is unnecessarily complicated and inefficient. First of all, use `CharBuffer.wrap(charSequence)`  right in the constructor to get the source buffer. You never need another source buffer. Then, (only) using `enc.encode(cb, bb, true);` is legit as there is no more content after this single source buffer.

Comment: Then, don’t focus on the single byte read method, which reasonable code shouldn’t invoke anyway. In `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`, you create a target buffer like `ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b, off, len);` then, the actual encoding operation is as simple as `if(!bb.hasRemaining()) return 0; if(!source.hasRemaining()) return -1; encoder.encode(source, bb, true); return bb.position();` (assuming `source` is the `CharBuffer` created in the constructor. The only remaining challenge is that in the unlikely case that `int read()` has been called you might have pending bytes in the buffer.

Comment: I made an example on https://ideone.com/IJsG3I Note that I dodged the complication of the single byte reading method by not implementing it at all and wrapping the input stream in a `BufferedInputStream` which takes care of it. The good thing about `BufferedInputStream` is that it goes out of the way whenever the caller provided a larger buffer and delegates directly to our stream, so in the normal case it doesn’t affect the performance and we have the encoder directly encoding from the (wrapped) `StringBuilder` to the (wrapped) caller’s target array.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I found surprisingly few (proper) examples of these nio classes, which I haven't used much. OK - I took a 20 second look so far - you wrapped the entire ```StringBuilder```  but the whole point is to *not* duplicate memory buffers ...

Comment: But *wrapping* does not duplicate memory.

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap(java.lang.CharSequence)): *Wraps a character sequence **into** a buffer.
The content of the **new**, read-only buffer will be the content of the given character sequence.* (my emph.) So it looks like it does

Comment: I don’t see how you read from this cite that the *new buffer* will duplicate memory, i.e. copy the data. There is a precise meaning for *wrapping*. See for example https://ideone.com/B6ychi the `CharBuffer` reflects the modified content of the `StringBuilder`, as it is only a wrapper around it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248944/discussion-between-g00se-and-holger).